# How to install matplotlib? [python]

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib, cryptography, pip

I have a problem when I want to install `matplotlib` via pip:
I did:

```
$ sudo pip install matplotlib
```

Out:

```
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (1.5.1)
launchpadlib 1.10.3 requires testresources, which is not installed.
paramiko 2.4.1 has requirement cryptography>=1.5, but you'll have cryptography 1.2.3 which is incompatible.
```

So then I did:

```
$ sudo pip install cryptography
```

Out: **same error as above.**

Portion of code:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Out:

```
2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ImportError: No module named matplotlib.pyplot
```

What should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried `sudo pip install -r matplotlib`?

Comment: try to upgrade the package with `pip install matplotlib --upgrade`

Comment: @AliYılmaz I update my question.

Comment: You're installing into python 2. Are you sure you're running python 2 and not 3? Try `pip3 install matplotlib`. I don't use Linux a huge amount but doesn't `sudo` install to a version of Python that is potentially different to the specific user's version?

Comment: @PRMoureu I did it, but the problem did not resolve.

Comment: are you trying this import in python3 or python2,  please check the comment from roganjosh

Comment: @PRMoureu yes, I update my question, I used `Python2`.

Comment: @roganjosh I update my question, I used `Python2` in my script and I have shown it with print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem:

I used **Pycharm** IDE and create a new project and select **"New environment using Vitualenv"** option instead of **"Existing interpreter"**, then I changed it to **"Existing interpreter"** option so that was right.

---

Thanks to all comments in my question (for updating `matplotlib` and attention to the *Python* version).